# Are variable values in Flutter's compiled release APK readable?

Tags: flutter, dart, obfuscation

In Flutter's documentation it is mentioned that flutter compiles DART code into native machine code. Then, how does then, does this machine code include variable names? then why does the documentation suggests obfuscating DART code before compilation? Is this "compiled native machine code" easily readable?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the question! Can you link to where the documentation suggests obfuscating Dart code?

Comment: @filiph hi, in this link the instructions are given for releasing your Flutter app, in which it includes optional obfuscation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release